# React (WebPack) scraping

Tags: reactjs, webpack

How do i can copy webpack files to work in a project?

The folders contain JS modules (scripts) with comments.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `create-react-app`(CRA). 
as far as i know you must eject from CRA to access webpack config in your project use either `npm eject` or `yarn eject`. 
This way you can't use migration script to upgrade your CRA any more.

Also you could use [React-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) without ejecting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react js with cli means(`create-react-app`) than you no need to copy webpack. Just use `npm eject`
if you are using CDN than try [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/part-1-react-app-from-scratch-using-webpack-4-562b1d231e75) one